# while routing to "/room/id" page, it is redirecting to two room routes like "/room/room/id", when I should have one room

Tags: python, django

my home page i.e "/" is listing all the room names with links, which should redirect to that particular room with that name. For example clicking on "Test Room1" should redirect me to "/room/1" with that name. But it is redirecting me to "/room/room/1" and however giving me the room name with id 1.

> views.py

```py
rooms = [
    {'id':1, 'name':'Test Room1'},
    {'id':2, 'name':'Test Room2'},
    {'id':3, 'name':'Test Room3'}
]
def home(request) :
    context = {'rooms':rooms}
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)

def room(request, pk) :
    room = None
    for i in rooms :
        if i['id'] == int(pk) :
            room = i
    
    context = {'room':room}        
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)
```

> urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'), 
    path('room/<str:pk>/', views.room, name='room')
]
```

> html template

```html
 {% for room in rooms %}
     <div>
         <h3>{{room.id}} : <a href="{% url 'room' room.id %}">{{room.name}}</a></h3>
     </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tested the provided code and it is properly redirecting to /room/1/

Comment: @WinmariManzano, when i inspect, i see <a href="/room/room/1">Test Room1</a>

Comment: For mine it is working as it should, href = "/room/1/", based on the code provided, I just copy pasted the whole code provided, I can't see where could that other /room/ may come from

Comment: @WinmariManzano, when i do this : href="room/{{room.id}}" in home.html, it works fine.  But i need to use url

Comment: I guess your `urls.py` is from your app's directory. Now show us the `urls.py` from your package's directory

Comment: @Zatigem, my app name is "base", and this is my urls.py code from root package : urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls')),
    path('room/', include('base.urls')),
]

Comment: no need to include twice `base.urls`. Just remove `path('room/', include('base.urls'))` and you're good

Comment: @Zatigem, thanks. Now It is working fine.